# How to make dropdown menu collapse after pressing it again?

Tags: html, css, button, dropdown

I want to make my dropdown menu's content to collapse once I click the dropdown menu button again.

This is my code:

```css
/* Dropdowns */

.dropdown_menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown_menu button {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown_menu:hover button {
  background-color: grey;
}

.dropdown_menu a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown_menu .content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-width: 90px;
}

.dropdown_menu:focus-within .content {
  display: block;
}


/* About Us */

.about_us {
  position: static;
}

#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>TECH TEAM <img src="imgs/ebmnhs_logo.jpg" style="position:relative; left:1200px;" height="50"></h1>
<hr>

<h2>Productivity Tools</h2>

<div class="dropdown_menu">
  <button>Text-generative AI</button>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://chat.openai.com/" target=_ blank>
      <span>ChatGPT</span>
      <br>
      <img src="imgs/antenna.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="https://bard.google.com/" target=_ blank>Bard</a>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="dropdown_menu">
  <button>Image-generative AI</button>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://www.midjourney.com/" target=_ blank>Midjourney</a>
    <a href="https://beta.dreamstudio.ai/" target=_ blank>DreamStudio</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="about_us">
  <div id="bottom">
    <hr>⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀</div>
  <div id="bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sit ipsa vitae sit voluptatem nesciunt quo asperiores molestiae ut beatae quibusdam ut accusantium consectetur. Hic quidem beatae ea sapiente laborum ut modi repellat ut veniam dolore.</div>
</div>
```

This is what my website looks like:
[image]
This is what it looks like after I press the dropdown menu:
[image]
And I want the menu to collapse like this once I press it again.
[image]
How do I achieve this?

Comment: You have chosen the element's focus to hold the state of the dropdown menu. Those. you need somehow to remove focus from the element after the second click.

Comment: You should use javaScript or jQuery to achieve it.

Comment: @AndreiFedorov any idea on how I can do it?

Comment: @AteetShekhar how can I accomplish this using javaScript?

Comment: Alternatively, you might get what you require by using HTML/CSS with label and input type=checkbox rather than a button.